# How do I modify this code to show only a specific DIV when Radio Button selected?

Tags: javascript

Currently pulling my hair out and can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I preface this with the fact that I am an absolute novice with JS and it is something I very rarely engage in, so please bear with my ignorance.

I've got this piece of very basic code currently:

```js
function paymentSelectionPayPal() {
  if (document.getElementById('paypaloption1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal').href = "test1.php";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('paypaloption2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal').href = "test2.php";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('paypaloption3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal').href = "test3.php";
  }
}
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption1">
<label for="paypaloption1">
    Text Here <span>£00.00</span>
    <div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div>
</label>

<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption2">
<label for="paypaloption2">
    Text Here <span>£00.00</span></label>

<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption3">
<label for="paypaloption3">
    Text Here <span>£00.00</span>
    <div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div>
</label>

<a href="" onclick='paymentSelectionPayPal()' id="paymentStartButtonPayPal">Pay securely with <span>PayPal</span></a>
```

It changes the hyperlink for the element `paymentStartButtonPayPal` subject to the radio button selected, which is great and it works fine, but we want to change it to showing an entirely different element (where `#paymentStartButtonPayPal` currently sits) subject to which radio button is clicked. But....I can't seem to get it to work, at all.

E.g. If `Radio Button 1` selected, show `DIV 1`, if `Radio Button 2` is selected, show `DIV 2`, and (you guessed it...) if `Radio Button 3` is selected, show `DIV 3`.

I've tried replacing:

```js
document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal').href = "test1.php";
```

with:

```js
document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal1').style.cssText = "display: block;";
```

or:

```js
document.getElementById('paymentStartButtonPayPal1').style.display = "block";
```

and I've added (with the CSS for these elements set to `display: none` in the stylesheet):

```html
<div id="paymentStartButtonPayPal1">PayPal Button 1</div>
<div id="paymentStartButtonPayPal2">PayPal Button 2</div>
<div id="paymentStartButtonPayPal3">PayPal Button 3</div>
```

But nothing happens, at all.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, if I'm doing something wrong?

Ready to launch this computer out of the window. Thanks in advance from a Brit at the end of his tether.

Comment: Your additions help improve the quality of the question , here are some tips to help you pose better questions in the future. Provide a [mcve] of what isn't working, currently you've give us some code that works, but only snippets of code that doesn't, somewhat out of context. Next give us a full description of the problem, what isn't happening that should, what is happening that shouldn't. Make sure to report any console errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without JavaScript, but is dependent on HTML structure so it can be fragile. We can leverage attribute selectors and adjacent sibling combinators to achieve this. Following is a more robust solution using JavaScript.

```css
[name=slider]:not(:checked) + label + div.info{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption1">
<label for="paypaloption1">Text Here <span>£00.00</span><div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div></label>
<div class="info">Info for radio one</div>

<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption2">
<label for="paypaloption2">Text Here <span>£00.00</span></label>
<div class="info">Info for radio two</div>

<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption3">
<label for="paypaloption3">Text Here <span>£00.00</span><div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div></label>
<div class="info">Info for radio two</div>

<a href="" onclick='paymentSelectionPayPal()' id="paymentStartButtonPayPal">Pay securely with <span>PayPal</span></a>
```

A more robust solution would use javasript. Here we use the value attribute of the check box to get the url and add a data attribute to store the id of the "info" div. It is almost always better to work with css classes instead of css attributes directly.

```js
//Get the link element
var link = document.getElementById("paymentStartButtonPayPal");

//Add event listeners to the radio buttons
document.querySelectorAll("[name=slider]").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //Set the link URL
  link.href = this.value
  //remove active class for the current one
  document.querySelector(".info.active").classList.remove("active");
  //Add active based on data attribute of clicked element
  document.getElementById(this.dataset.info).classList.add("active");  
}));
```

```css
.info:not(.active){
display:none;
}
```

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption1" value="test1.php" data-info="info1">
<label for="paypaloption1">Text Here <span>£00.00</span><div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div></label>


<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption2" value="test2.php" data-info="info2">
<label for="paypaloption2">Text Here <span>£00.00</span></label>


<input type="radio" name="slider" id="paypaloption3" value="test3.php" data-info="info3">
<label for="paypaloption3">Text Here <span>£00.00</span><div class="payment-selection-prompt">Prompt Text Here</div></label>


<a href="test1.php" id="paymentStartButtonPayPal">Pay securely with <span>PayPal</span></a>

<div class="info active" id="info1">Info for radio one</div>
<div class="info" id="info2">Info for radio two</div>
<div class="info" id="info3">Info for radio three</div>
```

Comment: Jon, that's wicked! Thank you so much for taking the time to provide the above. Two great options, thank you.

Comment: @TeddyS you're welcome. If it's helped you out, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick and/or upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code... you are getting the element `#paymentStartButtonPayPal1` but you haven't defined any element with such an ID.

Comment: I have defined three elements, as I've mentioned in the original post with "(where each radio button has a DIV specific to it, and the DIVs are set within the stylesheet to 'display: none', without an '!important' clause)".

Also, pretty bummed out that I've been given a negative score already...

Comment: And another negative score? Not cool. This is not previously answered, there are no typos, and I'm sure another novice will find themselves in the same position in due course.

Comment: The quality of this post was gnarly. Edit your post and perhaps more people will upvote it and give you a more thorough answer